# How solr filter result based on domain

Tags: solr

I am using a single solr server for two domains. I want to filter the result for each single domain.

I used this two method but rutn the same result.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=keywork&wt=xml&indent=true&fq=url:domain1.com

http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=keywork&wt=xml&indent=true&fq=url:domain2.com
```

How can I filter the result only for domain1.com and domain2.com?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the `url` filter to your search query?

Something like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=keywork%20AND%20url:domain2.com&wt=xml&indent=true
```

This would mean that the client would need to append the `url:domain` to every search query.

Comment: Not working. It still showing the same result as before. I saw some people said that use fq=site:domain.com but I don't get any result if I added this field.

Comment: Hmm - in cases like this, I use the Solr Admin page and analyze the query output with `debug=on`. Ref [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Screen). This will tell you why the unexpected matches are returned and help you tweak solr config/schema.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need to escape ":" in the domain.